# File processing perl - split produces very small arrays

Tags: regex, perl, text, field

Good day. I have a large text file I want to process, organised like so:

```
A
B 87368911
C 165368993    165369000       165369007       165369014       165369021       165369028
D 3299941
E 3221521
F 5909327
G 14740025      14740019        14740031        14740037
H 4446477      4640745
```

I want to split it up into a hash of arrays, with the first column as the key, with the values in an iterable array if there are any (in the case of A, there are none, as you may see). To this end, I have produced the following code (slightly amputated, I obviously open files and have surrounding code):

```
my %resolvedreads;

while (my $line = <IN>) {
    my @thisline = $line =~ m/(\S+)/g;
    $resolvedreads{$thisline[0]} = @thisline[1 .. $#thisline];
    print join "\t", @{$resolvedreads{$thisline[0]}}, "\n";
}
```

I didn't even really test this, because it seemed so trivial. Apparently I ought to have, because it's giving me this:

```
Use of uninitialized value $thisline[0] in hash element at resolved_reads_purifier.pl line X-1, <IN> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $thisline[0] in hash element at resolved_reads_purifier.pl line X, <IN> line 1.
Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at resolved_reads_purifier.pl line X, <IN> line 1.
```

I find myself somewhat baffled by this. Further investigation revealed that the line is indeed split, but every array has a length of 1 or 2.

So what gives? I feel like I've missed something fundamental here, and I'm at my wit's end. My previous code actually compiled despite being to my eyes almost entirely identical.

Comment: `$line =~ m/(\S+)/g` is commonly written `split ' ', $line`, and the preceding `chomp` is unnecessary for either

Comment: Quite, I simply forgot to remove chomp - I use it in my actual code. I have tried a variety of split variants as well as regexes to split the lines, and they all throw up the same curious output. Awk handles it perfectly, though, so I don't think it's a matter of unrecognised whitespace characters

Comment: Also, missing semicolon after the first line.

Comment: @user3034187: The first parameter to `split` is ordinarily processed as a regex, but passing a *single literal space* is a special case that does the same thing as `/\S+/g`, and is different from `split / /` which just splits on all occurrences of a space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I see a couple of things. The scalar vs. list context in assigning the array, mentioned above. The other thing is that your slice [1...#@array] starts with "1", but index 1 doesn't exist for row A, thus your error message. Here is working code:

```
use Modern::Perl '2013';
use Data::Dumper;

my $text = 'A
B 87368911
C 165368993    165369000       165369007       165369014       165369021       165369028
D 3299941
E 3221521
F 5909327
G 14740025      14740019        14740031        14740037
H 4446477      4640745';

my $fh;
open($fh, '<', \$text);

my %resolvedreads;

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
  chomp $line;
  my @thisline = $line =~ m/(\S+)/g;
  my $index    = shift @thisline;
  $resolvedreads{$index} = \@thisline;

}

say Dumper(\%resolvedreads);
```

Comment: Well, now I just feel foolish. Many thanks, I'm fairly sure that did it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when a file record has only got one field, `$#thisline` is zero so `@thisline[1 .. $#thisline]` is `@thisline[1 .. 0]` which is an empty list. Assigning that to a scalar given you `undef`

Aside from that there is a problem with

```
$resolvedreads{$thisline[0]} = @thisline[1 .. $#thisline]
```

because you are assigning a list to a scalar, and you will generally get only the last element of the list which is `$thisline[-1]`. You should really be assigning an *array reference* at this point

This is how I would code your problem

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %resolvedreads;

while ( <DATA>) {
    my ($key, @values) = split;
    next unless defined $key;        # Skip blank records
    $resolvedreads{$key} = \@values;
}

use Data::Dump;
dd %resolvedreads;

__DATA__
A
B 87368911
C 165368993    165369000       165369007       165369014       165369021       165369028
D 3299941
E 3221521
F 5909327
G 14740025      14740019        14740031        14740037
H 4446477      4640745
```

### output

```
{
  A => [],
  B => [87368911],
  C => [165368993, 165369000, 165369007, 165369014, 165369021, 165369028],
  D => [3299941],
  E => [3221521],
  F => [5909327],
  G => [14740025, 14740019, 14740031, 14740037],
  H => [4446477, 4640745],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$resolvedreads{$thisline[0]} = @thisline[1 .. $#thisline];
```

assigns an array to a hash value in scalar context, which is actually the same as

```
$resolvedreads{$thisline[0]} = scalar @thisline[1 .. $#thisline];
```

or

<strike>`$resolvedreads{$thisline[0]} = $#thisline;`</strike>

```
$resolvedreads{$thisline[0]} = $thisline[$#thisline];
```

From the rest of your post it looks like you wanted to assign an array reference to the hash value

```
$resolvedreads{$thisline[0]} = [ @thisline[1 .. $#thisline] ];
```

Equivalently, you could assign a list to a list in list context

```
@{$resolvedreads{$thisline[0]}} = @thisline[1 .. $#thisline];
```

Comment: I appreciate the response (and it does sound like this should resolve my 'small arrays' issue), but it's still not compiling on account of uninitialised values. Have you got any ideas for that?

Thanks all the same

Comment: Skip input lines with only whitespace?

Comment: There shouldn't be any, but I'll have a gander

Comment: `@thisline[1 .. $#thisline]` is not an array, it's a slice. [Slices in scalar context return the last item of the slice.](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices)